# Change id using image src jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm trying to create a tooltip effect where I'm creating a new DIV, filling it with content from another page then displaying it beneath an image when that image is moused over. Here is the code for creating the div, filling it with content and the mouseover.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<div id="DETAILS"> </div>').appendTo("body");
    $('#DETAILS').load('Test.html #CREATEYOUROWN');
    $("#DETAILS").hide();
    $('#PUZZLE').mouseover(function() {
        $("#DETAILS").show();
    });
    $('#PUZZLE').mouseleave(function() {
        $("#DETAILS").hide();
    });
});​
```

This works. However, I need to put this in a CMS, there will be around 20 of these set up as items and added to pages by a content editor, literally selected from a list when they're building a page. These items have the capacity to have javascript attributed to them but when they're added to the page they don't have their own id. The only thing that remains constant is the image source.

Is there a way of using the image source to change the id of the image?

I'm still quite new to jQuery so if there's a way of doing this entire thing better then I would be incredibly grateful for advice!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use a javascript templating engine like jsRender: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender

That way, you could build a template and have your IDs defined like so:

`<div id="mydiv_{{>counter}}"></div>`

jsRender demos and example code: http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/index.html

Also, keep in mind that there are many other engines out there, I just happen to like jsRender.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly the problem, but you could select an item by its source and change it's id like that using jQuery:

$('[src="image"]').attr('id', 'newId');

I don't know if this will help but try it.

Comment: I think this might be just the ticket, thanks very much! I'll give it a try in a bit and let you know.